# 3gp file format opens in safari but not in a UIWebView why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, safari, 3gp

I am trying to play a video in my iPhone application using the UIWebView component, the video is of format 3gp. If I try to open the url link to the video in the built in "Safari" application on my iPhone the video plays successfully without any problem, but when I try to open the link in the UIWebView i get an error message: "The opperation could not be completed".
Why is that happening?

My code:

```
NSURLRequest *pageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]]; [_webView loadRequest:pageRequest];
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the link you are trying to use exactly ? In general Safari is definitely more advanced than a pure UIWebView and you have to handle the variety of situations manually.

Comment: Sorry mate i can't send you the link i am using

Answer (score 0):

3GP is a container format. You should find what are the video and audio formats in it. Most probably your audio is with AMR encoding, which can't be played by UIWebView.